# Intel Core i3 CPU is not 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, pae, cpu

According to this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

the following Intel CPU's are 64bit:

```
Intel
F and 5x1 series Pentium 4 using the "Prescott" core
Pentium D
Core 2 (Solo, Duo & Quad)
Core i5 (all)
Core i7 (all)
```

Isn't the Core i3 64 bit too?

Comment: There are a bunch of CPUs missing from that list. AMD fusion, many atoms, many celerons, Pentium dual core (which is different than "D")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My laptop is an Core i3.  I have a dual boot - one with 64bit Ubuntu (12.04) and one with a 32bit Ubuntu (11.10).

So, yes - it is a 64bit capable machine.

*I'll update the wiki*

Comment: ... wiki has been updated.  The change is to be cleared by the maintainers - so it may take some time to appear.

Comment: ... wiki has now been updated

Answer (score 1):

They must have left it out. It is 64 bit, there is the Intel 64 support which is an x86-64 extension like AMD64.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i3_microprocessors

And here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_64#Intel_64

Answer (score 1):

All i3 supports Intel 64, which is Intel's implementation of x86-64, so yes, i3 is 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

All Intel Core i3 Processors (Sandy Bridge and Clarkdale ) are 64x architecture. Even though Clarkdale is based off of [Westmere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westmere_%28microarchitecture%29#Westmere) architecture, they use 64 bit architecture. I'm willing to bet this is a typo or something, considering the entire "i" generation was meant for 64 bit architecture to meet the expanding needs to computers RAM requirements, laptops incorporated graphics (internal GPU) and, higher processing/ thread count.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to determine if your processor is 64-bit is to look up at http://ark.intel.com/.

1. Select your Processor family from the Desktop processors category.
2. Select your model from the list.
3. Look for the Instruction Set field in the specification page.

If it says *„64-bit”*, you've got a 64-bit processor.